# Is it possible to get the attributes of an sc_fix thats been passed into a function?

Tags: fixed-point, systemc

Fairly new to systemc, I have been reading the documentation and I know that the `sc_fix` type has attributes for the word length and the integer length. Is it possible to pull these attributes? I can't seem to find mention of any function that would return, say, the number of bits a particular passed `sc_fix` variable would contain.

Any help or direction to relevant documentation would be appreciated.

Unless `sc_fixed` would be a better option? currently I am working on the assumptionthat sc_fixed is better to use as it is more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wl()` and `iwl()` methods.

`sc_fixed` is derived from `sc_fix`, which itself is derived from `sc_fxnum`. You can read documentation for `sc_fxnum` to learn about basic features of all fixed-point types.